# Check if product is in this category virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I would like to add either a class to each product depending on this category or to check if this product exist in this category and add some class

ex: 
now I have

```
<div class="product-price" id="productPrice<?php echo $this->product->virtuemart_category_id ?>">
```

it shows me what for ex. `h34` this is category class but the problem is that sometimes I ave multiple categories but product tkes only first one main category.

I need somethig like that

if product SHIRT exist in categoryID 77 add `class="label"`

some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use this query to check product is in categoty or not

```
SELECT * FROM `#__virtuemart_product_categories` WHERE `virtuemart_product_id` = <product_id> AND `virtuemart_category_id` = <category_id>
```